# Does php running on a webserver share the code segment

Tags: php, performance

Alternatively does it copy the compiled code from cache (APC) or load it from disk for each call.

The reason I am asking this is that I have a large data structure that I have initialized in a  file. Now I worry about the performance of the script.

Comment: You could use a profiler to see if your worries are warranted. PHP opcode caches cover .php scripts, but your question alludes to a plain data file being read in (where only the OS cache will matter).

Answer (score 0):

PHP is actually very efficient at dealing with large data-structures. It is, however, always going to store them in memory (which is *not* shared between calls). If it is large enough, you might want to consider buffering it piece by piece or storing it in a datastore of some sort. If your data file is `100MiB`, you're going to be loading at least `100MiB` plus the memory required by PHP with every call.

APC wont entirely help this situation either. When PHP loads initially (without APC), it will perform the following steps:

1. Read the entire file into memory
2. Lexing, it tokenizes the file into standard codes or "Lexicons" for the parser to read
3. Parsing, it then utilizes the tokens in the file to generate the required expressions for complication
4. Compiling, It takes the expressions and creates "opt-codes" similar to how Java "compiles"
5. Executing, the opt-codes are executed in the PHP runtime (data actually gets manipulated here)

You might have noticed that steps 1-4 are all redundant with multiple calls which is why compiled languages have a dedicated compiler to perform these steps and either a Runtime, VM, or OS to run the generated bytecode or binary on. APC actually tries to give PHP that same edge: by precompiling each file, it can then store the (typically smaller) precompiled, opt-code file into memory and access it when someone accesses the page.

The problem with your use-case is that this does absolutely nothing for literal data within a file. Data still must be declared and wont even be touched until step 5, which is why I am emphasizing the importance of perhaps using an external data store if you see a significant performance hit.

Please use a profile like [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) or something similar to gain some more insight on what is actually slowing your script down (if at all) so you can make a more informed decision on where to go from here.